# Completely RAW USB drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, drive

I'm having quite a lot of troubles in making a Kingston DT SE9 G2 work again.

It does not show on Windows (both in external devices and disk manager), but it appears here on Ubuntu.

However, whenever I click on it, it says

> Impossible to use «`usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_3.0_94DE80724792BF1069B340C6-0:0`»

and

> mount: only root can mount `/dev/sdb` on `/mnt/usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_3.0_94DE80724792BF1069B340C6-0:0`

Disk manager shows it, both its name, storage capacity and serial number, but it is only displayed as read only, so I can't really do anything with it.

Gparted doesn't allow me to do anything with it, too (the drive doesn't even appear there).

I tried everything, `testdisk`, mounting it, but all I am getting is a bunch of errors, permission denied on `dd` and broken partition tables.

Is there anything else I should try/do?

This is the lsblk output:

```
simone@Clarence:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part /media/simone/System reserves
├─sda2   8:2    0 203,7G  0 part /media/simone/044E2DEE4E2DD966
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0  18,1G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:5    0   1,4G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  29,3G  1 disk
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Said device happens to be `/dev/sdb`

Libparted output:

```
libparted : 2.3
======================

(gpartedbin:2811): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:2811): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:2811): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 26 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:2811): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 25 was not found when attempting to remove it
Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
Unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
/dev/sdb: unrecognized disk label
```

And here's `sudo parted -l /dev/sdb` output:

```
simone@Clarence:~$ sudo parted -l /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for simone: 
Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition table: msdos

 Number  Start  End    Size        Type      File system     Flag
 1      1049kB  368MB  367MB       primary   ntfs            avvio
 2      368MB   219GB  219GB       primary   ntfs
 3      219GB   221GB  1499MB      extended
 5      219GB   221GB  1499MB      logical   linux-swap(v1)
 4      221GB   240GB  19,5GB      primary   ext4


 Warning: unable to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
 Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognized disk label
```

Comment: Can you identify it using `lsblk`? If you can, try running `sudo gparted /dev/sdX`, where `sdX` is the drive as listed on `lsblk`'s output; if you can't, please [edit] your question and add the output of `lsblk` to it

Comment: Hey, kos, thanks for your reply! As you see I've edited my post. Since it shows there i tried going with gparted as you suggested, but with no luck:

Comment: This is the output (part 1)
======================
libparted : 2.3
======================

(gpartedbin:2811): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:2811): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6 was not found when attempting to remove it

Comment: (part 2)

(gpartedbin:2811): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 26 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:2811): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 25 was not found when attempting to remove it
Unable  to open /dev/sdb read-write (Read-only File System). /dev/sdb  hhas been opened read-only.
Unable to open /dev/sdbread-write (Read-only File System). /dev/sdb has been opened read-only.
/dev/sdb: unrecognized disk label

Comment: @Simone To provide new information, especially long command outputs, please [edit] your question and post it there, instead of in comments. That way, it improves the readability and makes it easier to help you. Please also use the code formatting button (**`{}`**) after selecting the output. And could you please also add the output of `sudo parted -l /dev/sdb`? Thank you.

Comment: And you could try `sudo mkdir /mnt/kingstonusbdrive && sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/kingstonusbdrive`. If it works, your stick is accessible through the directory `/mnt/kingstonusbdrive`.

Comment: Did you use dd to create an installer flash drive? That does not create a standard partition table flash drive, but hybrid flash/DVD. You usually have to use dd to zero out partition table in MBR as MBR has random data.

Comment: I *assume* from the `glib` errors that you ran `gparted` with `sudo` (sorry for the bad suggestion by the way, generally you should run graphical applications with `gksudo` or `sudo -H`, however in this specific case just `sudo` was fine). Can you confirm you used `sudo`?

Comment: @ByteCommander Sorry, just updated the original post with a nice and tidy output report. I tried using `sudo mkdir /mnt/kingstonusbdrive && sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/kingstonusbdrive` but it outputs `mount: unable to find /dev/sdb/mnt/kingstonusbdrive in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`. @kos yeah, I indeed used `sudo`

Comment: Did you forget the blank space between `/dev/sdb` and `/mnt/...`? It looks like that.

Comment: @ByteCommander Yep, I definitely forgot that. However, after retrying with the proper format, this is the output: `mount: block device /dev/sdb is write-protected, mounting read-only` and `mount: you must specify the filesystem type`

Comment: Does that device maybe have a physical write-protection switch? Look for little buttons or sliders on the case.

Comment: @ByteCommander 100% shrunk-to-the-bone metal body, google it and you'll see why I'm super sure about the lack of physical protection switches :^)

Comment: Oh, indeed. ^_^ Could have done that myself... I guess it's hard to build a switch into that case. Sorry, it was just a guess that came into my mind.

Comment: @ByteCommander is there anything else I should try? Is there any hope left or should I declare it officially dead?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm running out of ideas... I'm looking whether I can get some experts to look at your problem, but I can't promise anything.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got is a broken USB key.  Most of the time on brand names, the memory cells go first whereas with cheap brands it's the control circuit that goes first.

You've got a prime example of memory cell fatigue.  Just throw the key away and buy a new one. I would advise you to buy an [SLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell) USB key.  I've got an 8GB Kingston Data Traveller that is still working after 8-9 years now...

Granted, I only use it as a lubuntu boot disk to disinfect Windows computers, but it's still fast and works flawlessly.

SLC ones are about 2* more expensive then [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) ones, but they're 4-8 times as fast and last 4-8 times as long.  They're really SSDs on a stick!

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news!*

Comment: As you're a reputation 16 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: damnit, into the trash it goes I guess. Thanks for the reply

Comment: BTW do you happen to know what the chances are that this happened because of unsafe drive ejecting?

Comment: As USB sticks don't contain any moveable parts: ridiculously low...